# Finding the numbers in the Fibonacci sequence using recursion

Tags: java, fibonacci

Basically, I am looking to write a program that will give me the sequence but up to a certain number.  So let's say I want to go up to the 20th number or something.  I would like to know how to iterate it recursively so that it finds the values of each number in the sequence up to that number simply by using an `if()` statement. I don't have any code because all I know is how to do it with a `for` loop, which isn't the approach I need.

I know this much at least:

```
if n = 1 || n = 0
   return n;
else 
    return F(n-1) + F(n-2);
```

Code:

```
class Fibonocci {

    public static int factorial(int i,int n) { 
        System.out.println(i);

        if(i==n || n==0 || n==1) {  // base case;  when i = n, we're done.
            return n; 
        } else {
            return i + 1 + factorial(i+2,n); // iterative case; we're still adding values up.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fibonocci test= new Fibonocci();
        System.out.println( test.factorial(0,10) );
    }
}
```

I have been trying that and a whole bunch of other tries but I am still stumped. I know it goes `0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34...`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I add that bit there.  See I am just confused on this, I am just learning about recursion and not using a for loop to loop my stuff all the time.

Comment: Try first writing a recursive _multiplication_ function: `int mult(int a, int b)`. Multiply `a` times `b` using only addition on `b` and subtraction on `a`, and I think you'll be able to try the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @user1340054 Your logic is sound, did you try sticking that in a method?

Comment: Wouldn't even be able to begin on that, I know like if(x<5) run(x+1) and that will give you 1 2 3 4 5, if you print it out.

Comment: Could you explain that multiplication function to me?

Comment: Could I try to do fib(n+1) with a if(n<20) and would that give me what I'm looking for?

Comment: Your additions to the question don't really make much sense.  Remember how Fibonacci is defined:  F(1) = 1, F(2) = 1.  F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) for n > 2.

Answer (score 5):

You'd be surprised, but you're pretty much there with your code.  My feeling is that you're not comfortable with recursion yet.

### Anything you can do iteratively can be done recursively.

Think of it like this:  A loop (for, while, do-while) has an iterative step, and a condition to check to see if it's complete.  For instance, if I was adding all numbers from 1 to n:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // Condition to check completion
    sum += i;  // iterative step
}
```

To convert this to a recursive function, I require a condition for completion - called a **base case** - and an iterative step, or **iterative case**.  For the summation, my base case would be either when `i==n`.

```
public int sum(int i, int n) {
    if(i == n) {  // base case;  when i = n, we're done.
        return n; 
    } else {
        return i + sum(i+1, n); // iterative case; we're still adding values up.
    }
}
```

Apply this to your Fibonacci method, and I think that you'll be just fine.  No really, wrap it in a function call with the appropriate arguments, and you'll be fine.

---

### Further Clarification:  How Are the Calls Expanded?

Going back to the summation method, let's say that I want to sum the numbers between 1 and 10.  How are the calls expanded?

#### Iteratively

Not much doin' on the call stack, really.  It's going through a loop.  However, we can synthesize what is going on every time through.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
```

What this looks like through the loop:

```
Cycle #1: sum=1
Cycle #2: sum=3
Cycle #3: sum=6
Cycle #4: sum=10
Cycle #5: sum=15
Cycle #6: sum=21
Cycle #7: sum=28
Cycle #8: sum=36
Cycle #9: sum=45
Cycle #10: sum=55
Sum = 55
```

Seems right so far.

We are merely taking **one** element every time and adding it to a collective summation value.  In essence, 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 gets broken down into the following manner:

```
sum += 1 // 1 now
sum += 2 // 3 now
sum += 3 // 6 now
...
sum += 10 // 55 now
```

Recursively, there isn't any difference in how the values are gathered, but it's done slightly differently.

#### Recursively

Examine the calls for this:

```
public int sum(int i, int n) {
    return n == i ? n : i + sum(i+1, n); // ternary if-else statement, the exact same as the if-else in the above sum method.
}

1 + sum(2, 10)
1 + 2 + sum(3, 10)
1 + 2 + 3 + sum(4, 10)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + sum(5, 10)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + sum(6, 10)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + sum(7, 10)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + sum(8, 10)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + sum(9, 10)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + sum(10, 10)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10
55
```

It's doing, essentially, the same thing in the recursive call as it would in the serial call.  The expansion is a bit funny, but once you get used to it, it won't be a challenge.

From here, I strongly encourage you to try it out.  Don't be afraid to experiment; the information that's provided here is plenty sufficient to get you started.

Comment: What would i be within the fibonacci sequence?  It would be the number before it so would it be like n-1?

Comment: I'm not quite following what is going on at the return n+sum(i+1,n)

Comment: @user1340054: `i + sum(i+1, n)` (sorry, typo) is adding i to the next recursive call of `sum()`.  In other words, we're iterating through whatever value i is, and adding it to whatever value i+1 will be.

Comment: A call chain may look like, if I called it with i=10 and n=12:  `10 + sum(11, 12)` -> `10 + 11 + sum(12, 12)` -> `10 + 11 + 12` -> `33`.

Comment: so if I did in my main class sum(10,20) that would start i at 10 and then add that until i equals n?

Comment: That's exactly right.  You would get the sum from 10 to 20, which is...165.

Comment: I'm still confused about how to implement the fibonacci arguments into that method.  I see the adding and subtracting and it really did help me but I am just not quite getting this.  It is just really confusing me.

Comment: Could I do something like (i+1)+sum(i+2,n)?  I think that would still only give me one number rather than the whole sequence.

Comment: would the addition part within the () look like (i-2)+(i-1),n) or the other way around with i's?  I know it looks like I'm rushing, and I am since this is due tomorrow and I really need to figure this out.  I understand, I think, how that works now it is just a manner of trying to use that within the fibonacci sequence thats give me trouble.  I do know that it is added to last number in the sequence.

Comment: I can't afford to comment more, since the system wants to move this into chat (comments aren't meant for chats).  But in Fibonacci, the method is defined recursively as taking F(n-1) + F(n-2), for n >=0.  It's one part about *how* the recursive method is defined, and how it's written.

Answer (score 2):

Let me help you by writing a recursive factorial function :

The factorial method is defined as:

```
 if n == 0 || n == 1 return 1; else return n * F(n - 1);
```

which can be written in Java as:

```
public int factorial(int n) { 
   if(n == 0 || n == 1) { 
       return 1;
   } else { 
       return n * factorial(n - 1);
   }
}
```

So I think thats plenty for you to adapt and test for the fibonacci sequence given what you know.

Comment: So basically just put what I put at the top into code form and I should be fine?  I got 6765 but not the other numbers.

Comment: You may need to add some `println` statements at "choice" locations to print the _sequence_.

Comment: I'm just getting a bunch of random numbers when I try to put in a println statement.